# Is there any difference in calling delete as an operator or as a function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Is there any difference between the following statements if I'm using Visual Studio 2010:

```
wchar_t *wszChar = new wchar_t;
delete wszChar;
```

and

```
wchar_t *wszChar = new wchar_t;
delete(wszChar);
```

I've looked in the debugger and it seems that the same thing is done.

How about between:

```
wchar_t *wszChar = new wchar_t[10];
delete[] wszChar;
```

and

```
wchar_t *wszChar = new wchar_t[10];
delete(wszChar);
```

From what I've seen, in all 4 cases the memory is freed correctly.

Comment: First two are the same the last one is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first two are equivalent. You're not calling anything as a function, you're just putting a redundant set of parentheses around part of an expression -- about equivalent to `1+2*3` vs. `1+(2*3)` or the (all too common) `return(23);` vs. `return 23;`

In the second, you've left out the `[]` when you added the parentheses, causing undefined behavior.

A typical (but definitely *not* guaranteed) result of the latter will be freeing the block of memory itself, but failing to invoke destructors for the items in the array. In your case (array of `char` that doesn't have a destructor) that won't be detectable though. You may also get other side-effects though, such as the OS halting execution of the program.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct item {
    item() { std::cout << "create\n"; }
    ~item() { std::cout << "destroy\n"; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "test 1\n";
    item *items = new item[5];
    delete [] items;
    std::cout << "test 2\n";
    item *items2 = new item[5];
    delete items2;
}
```

Result:

```
test 1
create
create
create
create
create
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
test 2
create
create
create
create
create
destroy
```

...followed by execution being halted by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

`delete(wszChar)` isn't calling a function - it's the delete operator with the expression `(wszChar)` as an operand.

In your last example, calling non-array delete on a pointer that was created with array new is undefined behavior. The fact that it works the same in your particular example (ie., there's no obvious problem) is one way that UB can manifest.  If you change the example to use a an object with a destructor that does some actual work instead of `wchar_t` you'll see a difference in behavior.

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like a function call, is actually the ordinary `delete` operator followed by the *primary-expression* `(wszChar)`, which is equivalent to

```
delete wszChar;
```

Your second example uses `delete` where `delete[]` should be used, resulting in *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

No difference. Using `()` doesn't mean calling a function, it's just combining operators `()` and `delete`:

```
delete (wszChar);
```

Don't forget using `[]` to avoid undefined behavoir.

---

To clarify, remember keyword `sizeof`. You can use it `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete(wszChar);
```

is equivalent to:

```
delete wszChar;
```

Just remember that for every `new` a `delete` should be called and for every `new[]` a `delete[]` should be called, if you mix it this way:

```
wchar_t *wszChar = new wchar_t[10];
delete(wszChar);
```

the behavior is ***undefined***